# How to keep data-fixedvalue in different textboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two different textboxes and a function to keep some part of values in each of them even if the user deletes textboxes data-fixedvalue will be back .

I worte the below code but this code only works for the first class for the next class it does not consider data-fixedvalue.

How can I fix this issue?

Here is my snippet :

```js
var el = document.querySelector( ".telinfo" );
el.addEventListener( "keyup", handleEv);
el.addEventListener( "blur", handleEv);
function handleEv( event )
{
   var thisObj = event.currentTarget;
   var fixedValue = thisObj.getAttribute( "data-fixedvalue" );
   if ( thisObj.value.indexOf( fixedValue )  != 0 )
   {
   console.log(thisObj.value, fixedValue);
   event.preventDefault();
   thisObj.value = fixedValue;
   }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="+98912314789" class="telinfo" data-fixedvalue = "+9891" maxlength="13">
<input type="text" value="+7812345678" class="telinfo" data-fixedvalue = "+78">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. You have multiple elements so use [document.querySelectorAll( ".telinfo" )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and then iterate over all of them (it's an array) with [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) cause you need to add the event listener to every element you want to handle the event.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll( ".telinfo" );

elements.forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener( "keyup", handleEv);
    element.addEventListener( "blur", handleEv);
});

function handleEv( event ) {
    var thisObj = event.currentTarget;
    var fixedValue = thisObj.getAttribute( "data-fixedvalue" );
    if ( thisObj.value.indexOf( fixedValue )  != 0 ) {
        console.log(thisObj.value, fixedValue);
        event.preventDefault();
        thisObj.value = fixedValue;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="+98912314789" class="telinfo" data-fixedvalue = "+9891" maxlength="13">
<input type="text" value="+7812345678" class="telinfo" data-fixedvalue = "+78">
```